# Building Chart.js master - generated .js gives errors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am getting an error when I work with a version of Chart.js master that I compiled myself. I must be missing some kind of dependency that I've missed in the documentation. I have no clue what .js I need to include.

When I move my mouse-cursor over the chart I get a bunch of errors related to a missing Color library. Which one am I missing exactly?

```
TypeError: i.color(...).saturate is not a function
```

Edit:
I have created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o9ebb5sq/

This piece of code does not show the problem (using Chart 2.0.0-Beta). This is why I copied this release into my software and tried again. The problem I am describing disappears.

I am running a master build (created using 'gulp build') Which makes me think the problem is either present in git master, or it is caused by my build environment.

I have installed the following npm packages before I ran `gulp build`

- gulp 3.9.0
- gulp-concat 2.6.0
- gulp-connect 2.2.0
- gulp-html-validator 0.0.5
- gulp-jshint 1.12.0
- gulp-karma 0.0.5
- gulp-replace 0.5.4
- gulp-size 2.0.0
- gulp-uglify 1.4.2
- gulp-util 3.0.7
- semver 5.0.3
- karma 0.13.14
- inquirer 0.11.0

I expect that maybe I am missing something here or that one of the packages I've used to build Chart.js has an issue.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle set up? cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the package.json on 2.0 they have included a new dependency `"color": "git://github.com/chartjs/color"` you will also need to include this. Odd thing is they alias this to a helper

```
   color = helpers.color = function(color) {
        if (!window.Color) {
            console.log('Color.js not found!');
            return color;
        }
        return window.Color(color);
    },
```

So I would have expected for you to see the log unless you already have something in the global namespace named `Color`.